# Display Image in a new intent

Tags: android, android-intent, android-image

This question has been asked many times and i have used a code

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    intent.setDataAndType(
            Uri.parse("file://"
                    + Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()
                    + "/Pictures/asd.jpg"), "image/*");
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

This code does open an image, but it asks for action, to open in Gallery or Photos etc. I want my app not to ask for an option and directly open in Gallery mode. How to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Use this method hopes this works.

```
    public void openInGallery(String imageId) {      
          Uri uri=MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI.buildUpon().appendPath(imageId).build();
          Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
          startActivity(intent);
        }
```

Comment: What would be imageId? is it the imageName?

Comment: give the full path i havenot tried it fully try and let me if you face any issue.

Comment: can u please tell me how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know you can't do it, however you can make a little trick when trying to open gallery by package name.

Actually it not recomended, but when it is very important for you you can try. Look at this post: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-developers/VYLJOAJZ6n0